# How to make a condition block in java execute only once?

Tags: java, if-statement

Consider a file reading scenario, where the first line is a header. When looping the file line by line, an 'if condition' would be used to check whether the current line is the first line.

```
for(Line line : Lines)
{
     if(firstLine)
     {
         //parse the headers
     }else
     {
         //parse the body
     }
}
```

Now since the control has come inside the 'if block', in all the other occurrences, it is waste to check the 'if condition'.

Is there any concept in java so that, once after executing, the particular line of code just vanishes away?

I think this would be a great feature if introduced or does it already exist?

**Edit:** Thank you for your answers. As I see, there were many approaches based on 'divide the data set'. So instead of 'first line', consider there is a 'special line'..

```
for(Line line : Lines) //1 million lines
{
     if(specialLine)
     {
         //handle the special line
     }else
     {
         //handle the rest
     }
}
```

In the above code block, suppose the special line comes only after half way to 1 million iterations, how would you handle this scenario efficiently?

Comment: Its nothing to do with java some basic logic just use a flag and reverse the condition written above.

Comment: There is no such thing in Java. But: If you have let's say one header line and 200 million lines of body it would be wise to just parse the header outside the for loop. If you have 20 lines in total it doesn't matter anyways as the performance difference can be neglected. Also JIT will optimize it anyways if deemed necessary.

Comment: You can split the lines array when firstline executes and break from current loop. and do the other work with remaining splitted array in another loop. With this you can save the condition execution for the remaining array.

Comment: Why do you want this? There is branch prediction so performance wise it doesn't make much of a difference.

Answer (score 5):

What about changing the logic a little!

So because the header is the first line you can get the firstLine and parse it alone, then start to parse the body starting from the second line :

```
List firstLine = Lines.get(0);
//parse the headers        ^------------------Get the first line
for (int i = 1; i < Lines.size(); i++) {
    //       ^--------------------------------Parse the body starting from the 2nd line
    //parse the body
}
```

In this case you don't need any verification.

Comment: Upvote here - you found a nice balance between writing "special" code ... and not going completely overboard. I find the other answers are really "off" into *premature* optimization land.

Answer (score 2):

You could (pseudo code) simply reverse things:

```
// parse headers
for(Line line: remainingLines)
{
```

But then: you would be using a simple boolean flag for that check. That if check is almost for free, and even more: **when** this loop sees so many repetitions that it is worth optimizing, the JIT will kick in and create **optimized** code for it.

And if the JIT doesn't kick in, it isn't *worth* optimizing this. And of course, there is also *branch prediction* on the hardware level - in other words: you can expect that modern hardware/software makes sure that the optimal thing happens. Without you doing much else besides writing clear, simple code.

In that sense, your question is a typical example of premature optimization. You worry on the wrong aspects. Focus on writing clean, simple code that gets the job done. Because that is what enables the JIT to do its runtime magic. And most optimisations that you apply at jave source code level do not matter at runtime.

Comment: The only correct answer. The JIT is clever enough to spot such simple optimizations. Trying to be more clever than they are is not going to get you far in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Also maybe add "branch prediction" to your answer so people can further investigate if they are interested in the inner workings of "what is (potentially) optimized here".

Answer (score 2):

Try to divde the dataset.

```
public List head(List list) {
    return list.subList(0, 1);
}

public List tail(List list) {
    return list.subList(1, list.size());
}

head(lines).foreach( lambda: //parse the header)
tail(lines).foreach( lambda: //parse the body)
```

Comment: Very clever! Just have to make sure the list size is greater than 1. Otherwise you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: The context of this problem doesn't contain enough references to input or output data and higher context. Anyway I would validate the dataset on some layer above.

Comment: What do you mean? The context is a `List`. In the original code you can't get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for any size of `List`. A size check should absolutely be done here.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to use some kind of flags to ensure that you parse the first line as header only once.

```
boolean isHeaderParsed = false

for(Line line: Lines)
{
 if(!isHeaderParsed && firstLine)
 {
     //parse the headers
     isHeaderParsed = true
 }else
 {
     //parse the body
 }
}
```

This will achieve what you are looking for. But if you are looking for something more fancier, Interfaces is what you need.

```
Parser parser = new HeaderParser()
for(Line line: Lines)
{
  parser = parser.parse();
}

// Implementations for Parser
public class HeaderParser implements Parser{
    public Parser parse() {
         // your business logic
         return new BodyParser();
    }
}

public class BodyParser implements Parser{
    public Parser parse() {
         // your logic
         return this;
    }
}
```

These are commonly referred to as [Thunks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk)

Comment: What does `this()` accomplish? Do you just mean, `this`?

Comment: Already **firstLine** is one such boolean like the **isHeaderParsed**. So your first block of code does not change anything. But your second code block is interesting. But don't you think even in here, instead of a 'if block', the assignment block 'parser=parser.parse()' is coming through out the for loop? If the for loops is going to run a million times, a million assignments..

Answer (score 1):

Since everybody else is posting some weird answers. You could have an interface.

```
interface StringConsumer{
    void consume(String s);
}
```

Then just change interfaces after the first attempt.

```
StringConsumer firstLine = s->{System.out.printf("first line: %s\n", s);};
StringConsumer rest = s->{System.out.printf("more: %s\n", s);};

StringConsumer consumer = firstLine;

for(String line: lines){
    consumer.consume(line);
    consumer = rest;        
}
```

If you didn't like the assignment, you can make consumer a field and change it's value in the firstConsumer consume method.

```
class StringProvider{
    StringConsumer consumer;
    List<String> lines;
    //assume this is initialized and populated somewhere.

    void process(){
        StringConsumer rest = s->{System.out.printf("more: %s\n", s);};
        consumer = s->{
            System.out.printf("firstline: %s\n", s);
            consumer = rest;
        };
        for(String line: lines){
            consumer.consume(line);
        }
    }
```

}

Now the first consume call will switch the consumer that is being used. and subsequent calls will to the 'rest' consumer.

Comment: I like your approach. But even in there, the line **consumer = rest;** loops through out the for loop. What if the for loop run for some million lines?

Comment: @BalajiVignesh If you were to execute that line enough that it could make a performance hit, it will certainly get optimized out. I doubt you could fashion a benchmark that would show the difference reliably. Ill add The way to do it with a field so you don't need an assignment in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have a boolean flag out side of if-else and change the status of flag when it entered in method. also evaluate this flag along with condition

```
boolean flag=true;

for(Line line: Lines)
{
     if(firstLine && flag)
     {
 flag=false;
         //parse the headers
     }else
     {
         //parse the body
     }
}
```

Comment: firstLine is such a flag... this did not change a thing.

Comment: it will change once enters in if block

Comment: What I said is that firstLine already is a boolean value doing the exact same thing as your boolean. firstLine is a flag.

Answer (score 0):

As no one said that, I'll just go ahead and say that this extra `if` statement is actually pretty cheap, performance wise.

At the lowest level of your machine, there is a thing called *branch prediction*. `if` statements tend to be pretty expensive when the hardware can't predict its result. But when it does get it right, testing a boolean with an `if` comes out pretty much for free. And since your `if` will 99.99% of the times evaluate to `false`, any hardware will do just fine

So don't worry about that too much. You're not wasting cycles there.

And answering your question... It kind of exists already. It doesn't vanish, but if you code it right it should be pretty close to vanished